# Do I need to submit separate sitemaps for language based subdirectories?

Tags: seo, sitemap, language, subdirectory

my company uses a site that targets the different regions we are based in using subdirectories (`www.example.com/en-sg/`) instead of subdomains (`www.en-sg.example.com`). Can I ask if I will need to create sitemaps for each of the different `/xx-xx/` and submit them to Google Search Console?

Each subdirectory contains some duplicated content from the `/en/` subdirectory. (we treat the `/en/` directory as the root), mostly product pages and some blog content as blogs are managed separately across the subdirectories.

As the different subdirectories serve different regions, will creating sitemaps for each subdirectory help them rank better in their specific regions? Rather than prioritise the `/en/` pages?

Comment: Do you use hreflang tags in your pages to tell Google about the different languages?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller , No this site does not. We are in the works of introducing IP Geolocation into the site to help with that but from an SEO standpoint, i'm not sure if this would help Google push the region specific pages first before the "/en/" pages.

Comment: IP Geolocation can kill your SEO if you implement it such that every page can redirect based on the visitor's IP address.  Doing that will make your site uncrawlable by search engines and cause Google to mostly only index you English site.  It can be effective to redirect the base home URL based on IP with a fallback to a list of languages if there is no match.  It is also possible to put a notice on every page saying "This is the English site but it looks like you might prefer German, click here to get to the German site."

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and advice on this! Yeah I can see why this isn't good for the site. Constant redirection will not fare well for user experience as well... But yeah... My site is restricted by the fact that we do not have subdomains for the different languages is causing me issues on duplicated content and having the right pages appear on the SERPs in the right location... What a mess....